# Condition not worked in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am newer in mongoDB. My actual data contains following information

```
> db.admins.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53cdfb5518dd87a6169c7907"), 
  "username" : "admin", 
  "email" : "sadikhasan.palsaniya@slktechlabs.com", 
  "password" : "b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203" }
```

When I write following query it returns `none` (No any record)

```
> db.admins.find( {"OR":{"username":"admin","email":"admin"},
                   "AND":{"password":"b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203"}
                  });
```

Where am I wrong I don't know why it is not work. If more information needed I help you.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation on the $or operator?

Comment: No, Here i mentioned query is auto generated by cakephp.

Comment: You need to talk to the cakephp guys then because that query is seriously wrong

Comment: Can you give me equivalent mongodb query?

Comment: `db.admins.find({$or: [{'username': 'admin'}, {'email' : 'admin'}], 'password' : 'b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203'})` would be the correct query

Comment: Not working dear I tried it.

Comment: Did you try the small edit I put in since I wrote the $or wrong?

Comment: sammaye's query is correct.

`db.admins.find({$or: [{'username': 'admin'}, {'email' : 'sadikhasan.palsaniya@slktechlabs.com'}], 'password' : 'b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203'})`

email is non 'email' but "sadikhasan.palsaniya@slktechlabs.com", in your query

Comment: If I write this query `db.admins.find({$OR: [{'username': 'admin', 'email' : 'admin'}], 'password' : 'b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203'})` then give error like `error: {
 "$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $OR",
 "code" : 17287
}`

Comment: Also you took on my coding mistake in the $or, refresh the page and copy again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All MongoDB operators start with a `$` and are in lower-case.
2. The [`$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) operator takes an array of objects of which only one entry needs to be fulfilled
3. [`$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/) is redundant in most cases. When you pass an object with multiple fields, they all have to be fulfilled by default.

So try this:

```
db.admins.find({
    "$or":[ 
          { "username":"admin" },
          { "email":"admin" }
    ],
    "password":"b3dfaf29547a69faaaaf63e1223bb4c479c80203"}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help I got solution and I accept it. I posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881556/cakephp-with-mongodb-where-condtion-not-worked which is not worked